# "Data retrieval failed for the subreport" report created in VS 2017

Tags: subreport, logfile

I have created Main report and sub-report in Visual Studio 2017.

Sub-report "preview" works fine with dataset based on stored procedure.

Main report has a stored procedure that brings all "project numbers" which are the parameters for sub-reports. Both stored datasets are based on the same(shared) datasource which has specific credentials for the database. Both datasets have the same **name**.
Preview of Main report brings the correct number of sub-reports, but instead of data, displays **"Data retrieval failed for the subreport"** for both of them.

Now the worst part: I'm running windows 11 and there is NO **Log files** for ReportServices in the directory everybody is pointing to. The path looks like this "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80 or 90 or 110 or 120 or 130 or 150 or ClientSDK"
There is no ReportingServices Folder on my hard drive.
So I do not know WHAT causes the error.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I would look at is the parameter value being passed to the subreport. Assuming you have a table in your main report with contains a subreport, add an extra column that show the value of the parameter you are passing. Also, edit your question to show how you have the parameter setup in both the main report (on the subreport properties) and in the subreport definition itself. It might be something as simple as an invalid value being passed to the subreport

Comment: Yes Alan! It was simple - I missed the creation of the second dataset for Main report that actually provides the parameters to the sub. Sorry I didn't follow the instructions closely. However the question regarding Log Files location is still a mystery to me...  Thank you!

Comment: I 'think' the log files will not get populated if running  from Visual Studio anyway. The output window should show you any errors whilst developing. I can't be sure and I can't check right now (just shut the work laptop down as it's nearly 11pm) but if you can't see the errors in VS output and/error windows then I would post a separate question